# External HDD on a Windows 8.1 HP

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I have Win 8.1. First day in Windows. Just moving over from Mac. Can;t affored a new Mac. I have lots of data on an external HDD from my Mac. I want to access those files on the PC. When I plug the HDD in to the USB port, the computer acknowledges its presence with a sound - but it does not reveal the HDD anywhere. I have tried Disk Manager. I tried an HDD formatted on a older HP PC. Nothing there either. Is there any way to cause the PC to show me the files on the HDD??

Comment: When you first plug an external HDD in, you need to wait for some time-there should be a windows saying `Setup is installing the necessary files`. Does the HDD show in Windows Explorer>This PC?

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 possible reason for this. First one is that Mac and Windows use different file systems. If you want to use an external HDD with both of them you should format it in FAT32.
Another thing is that Windows 8.1 often has issues with the USB 3.0 drivers. Make sure you are connecting the HDD to a USB 2.0 port on the PC.

Comment: Farmat FAt32 **or** install a HFS reader on the windows install.